# ImportError: No module named win32timezone when i make a singleone exe from a python script with pyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I have a script which works when is a `py` file, but when i use pyInstaller to make one single exe file from that script i will get an error : `ImportError: No module named win32timezone`.
I import in script:

```
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
```

and some another modules like `subprocess, os, time` but i think that 3 are the problem.
Anybody know what is wrong? Thanks!

Comment: try changing .spec file, sounds like job for hidden imports...

Comment: I was getting a 'win32timezone' module not found, when a FileChooser would try to open in my .exe build (no problems in the same program running as 'python main.py'). Turns out the hidden-import mentioned below was the correct thing to fix it. In my .spec file I made sure that the hiddenimports section of Analysis read: `hiddenimports=['win32timezone']` and then my runtime ImportError was fixed.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I think you need to follow this section of the Pyinstaller manual:

https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#id67

> Listing Hidden Imports
>
> If Analysis thinks it has found all the imports, but the app fails
>   with an import error, the problem is a hidden import; that is, an
>   import that is not visible to the analysis phase.
>
> Hidden imports can occur when the code is using **import** or perhaps
>   exec or eval. Hidden imports can also occur when an extension module
>   uses the Python/C API to do an import. When this occurs, Analysis can
>   detect nothing. There will be no warnings, only an ImportError at
>   run-time.
>
> To find these hidden imports, build the app with the -v flag (Getting
>   Python's Verbose Imports above) and run it.
>
> Once you know what modules are needed, you add the needed modules to
>   the bundle using the **--hidden-import= command option**, or by editing
>   the spec file, or with a hook file (see Understanding PyInstaller
>   Hooks below).

Answer (score 21):

**the -v flag no longer works (shows the version now).**

First, find out which module is missing. You can do this by executing the exe through PowerShell/cmd. For example, if your file is "project.exe", open a PowerShell window in its directory and use the command: `.\project.exe`.

Use this to build the exe:
`pyinstaller --hiddenimport win32timezone -F a.py`

- win32timezone was the missing module.
- Use either -F or --onefile to create a standalone, redistributable exe.
- You can use --hiddenimport multiple times if you have multiple modules missing.

Reference: https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/usage.html

Comment: Solved my problem. Thank you very much my friend.
I wish for you good luck.

Answer (score 0):

and only you import win32timezone in the module

import win32com.client as win32
import win32timezone