# Unable to read Outlook Mail Items using win32com when run as exe build using pyInstaller - Python code works

Tags: python, outlook, pyinstaller, win32com, mailitem

I have following code which is able to read Mail Items from outlook and download the attachment when python code is run using eclipse. however, when the same code is compiled to an exe using pyinstaller, it fails to read the mail items with error: ComObject Unknown

The following code reads email item in a folder and downloads excel attachment from mail with specific subject. then strips off the password from the downloaded xls file and saves it as xlsx file for further processing.

The code below runs fine when run in eclipse environment or when called using python.exe from command prompt. but fails to recognize email item when run using exe compiled by pyinstaller.
I am using Windows 10 and outlook 2016 over exchange server
what is it that i am missing here?
below is the code block:

```
import win32com.client as wc
from datetime import date
import os
import configparser

print('Reading Config file')
config=configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read('ReadOutlook.config')
configuration=config['DEFAULT']
mailboxname=configuration['mailboxname']
mailfolder_to_look_for=configuration['mailfolder_to_look_for']
downloadpath=configuration['downloadpath']
ULMISPath=configuration['ULMISPath']
CFMISPath=configuration['CFMISPath']
ulmis_password=configuration['ulmis_password']
cfmis_password=configuration['cfmis_password']
ulmisSubjectcontent=configuration['ulmisSubjectcontent']
cfmisSubjectcontent=configuration['cfmisSubjectcontent']
ulmisfilenamesearch=configuration['ulmisfilenamesearch']
cfmisfilenamesearch=configuration['cfmisfilenamesearch']
print (date.today())

outlook = wc.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
root = namespace.Folders.Item(mailboxname)
print(root.Name)
#print(root.Name)
MyMails=root.Folders.Item(mailfolder_to_look_for)

def Remove_password_xlsx(filename, pw_str,newfilename):
    print('opening Excel Application')
    xcl = wc.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    print('opening file:' ,filename)
    wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    print('Removing password for',filename)
    wb.SaveAs(filename, None,'','')
    print('Now saving as xlsx',newfilename)
    wb=xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename,False,False,None)
    wb.SaveAs(newfilename, FileFormat=wc.constants.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,CreateBackup=False)
    xcl.Quit()
for mailitem in range(len(MyMails.Items),0,-1):
    print(MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject)
    try:
        if(MyMails.Items[mailitem].ReceivedTime.date()==date.today() 
           and ((MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find(ulmisSubjectcontent)!=-1 
                 and MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find('With Collection')!=-1) 
                 or MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find(cfmisSubjectcontent)!=-1)):
            print(MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject)
            # if i.Attachments:
            for f in MyMails.Items[mailitem].Attachments:
                if f.FileName.find(ulmisfilenamesearch)!=-1:
                    f.SaveAsFile(downloadpath + '\\ULMIS.xls')
                    Remove_password_xlsx(downloadpath+'\\ULMIS.xls'
                                         , ulmis_password,ULMISPath)
                    print('removing ULMIS.xls')
                    os.remove(downloadpath+'\\ULMIS.xls')
                    break
                else:
                    if f.FileName.find(cfmisfilenamesearch)!=-1:
                        f.SaveAsFile(downloadpath + '\\CFMIS.xls')
                        Remove_password_xlsx(downloadpath +'\\CFMIS.xls'
                                             , cfmis_password,CFMISPath)
                        print('removing CFMIS.xls')
                        os.remove(downloadpath+'\\CFMIS.xls')
                        break
                    
    except:
        print('an error occurred')
        pass
```

> Printing the Mail Subject gives error as:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "ReadOutlook.py", line 45, in module File >"win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 279, in **getitem** File >"win32com\client\util.py", line 37, in **getitem** File >"win32com\client\util.py", line 56, in __GetIndex IndexError: list index >out of range

> IndexError: list index out of range
> Failed to execute script 'ReadOutlook' due to unhandled exception!

Comment: What is the value of `mailitem` when you get the error? I have had similar odd behaviour recently when using `[]` indexing: it seemed to switch from being zero-based to 1-based. Try re-installing the pywin32 package, then using `outlook = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")` instead of `Dispatch()`.  This should refresh the 'glue' code in win32com that converts the `[]` indexing operator to the `getitem()` call.

Comment: @DS_London

Thanks for the response.

mailitem gave  correct values - count of mail items - this was just a loop so that i access data from latest first.

outlook = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
This resolved my issue.
After adding above, i got error of win32timezone which i resolved by referring: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212949/importerror-no-module-named-win32timezone-when-i-make-a-singleone-exe-from-a-py
Finally added xcl=wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
And my code is working fine now - Thanks.

How do i accept this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from the comments reced above by DS_London, i have now changed my code as follows:

```
import win32com.client as wc
from datetime import date
import os
import configparser
# while creating exe on pyinstaller use "win32timezone" in hidden import section
print('Reading Config file')
config=configparser.ConfigParser()
config.sections()
config.read('ReadOutlook.config')
configuration=config['DEFAULT']
mailboxname=configuration['mailboxname']
mailfolder_to_look_for=configuration['mailfolder_to_look_for']
downloadpath=configuration['downloadpath']
ULMISPath=configuration['ULMISPath']
CFMISPath=configuration['CFMISPath']
ulmis_password=configuration['ulmis_password']
cfmis_password=configuration['cfmis_password']
ulmisSubjectcontent=configuration['ulmisSubjectcontent']
cfmisSubjectcontent=configuration['cfmisSubjectcontent']
ulmisfilenamesearch=configuration['ulmisfilenamesearch']
cfmisfilenamesearch=configuration['cfmisfilenamesearch']
print (date.today())

# outlook = wc.Dispatch("Outlook.Application")
outlook = wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
namespace = outlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
root = namespace.Folders.Item(mailboxname)
print(root.Name)
#print(root.Name)
MyMails=root.Folders.Item(mailfolder_to_look_for)

def Remove_password_xlsx(filename, pw_str,newfilename):
    print('opening Excel Application')
    xcl=wc.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Excel.Application")
    # xcl = wc.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    print('opening file:' ,filename)
    wb = xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename, False, False, None, pw_str)
    xcl.DisplayAlerts = False
    print('Removing password for',filename)
    wb.SaveAs(filename, None,'','')
    print('Now saving as xlsx',newfilename)
    wb=xcl.Workbooks.Open(filename,False,False,None)
    wb.SaveAs(newfilename, FileFormat=wc.constants.xlOpenXMLWorkbook,CreateBackup=False)
    xcl.Quit()
for mailitem in range(len(MyMails.Items),0,-1):
    # print(MyMails.Items[mailitem].ReceivedTime.date())
    try:
        if(MyMails.Items[mailitem].ReceivedTime.date()==date.today() 
           and ((MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find(ulmisSubjectcontent)!=-1 
                 and MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find('With Collection')!=-1) 
                 or MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject.find(cfmisSubjectcontent)!=-1)):
            print(MyMails.Items[mailitem].Subject)
            # if i.Attachments:
            for f in MyMails.Items[mailitem].Attachments:
                if f.FileName.find(ulmisfilenamesearch)!=-1:
                    f.SaveAsFile(downloadpath + '\\ULMIS.xls')
                    Remove_password_xlsx(downloadpath+'\\ULMIS.xls'
                                         , ulmis_password,ULMISPath)
                    print('removing ULMIS.xls')
                    os.remove(downloadpath+'\\ULMIS.xls')
                    break
                else:
                    if f.FileName.find(cfmisfilenamesearch)!=-1:
                        f.SaveAsFile(downloadpath + '\\CFMIS.xls')
                        Remove_password_xlsx(downloadpath +'\\CFMIS.xls'
                                             , cfmis_password,CFMISPath)
                        print('removing CFMIS.xls')
                        os.remove(downloadpath+'\\CFMIS.xls')
                        break
                    
    except:
        # print('an error occurred')
        pass
```

after this, I was getting error of missing import for win32timezone, which I corrected by adding hidden_import parameter in pyInstaller while building the exe - followed this post for it:
[ImportError: No module named win32timezone when i make a singleone exe from a python script with pyInstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33212949/importerror-no-module-named-win32timezone-when-i-make-a-singleone-exe-from-a-py)